# How can I display data in recyclerview only with specific value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sorting, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make something like a diary for storing refuelings of the car using SQLite database, but I don't know how to limit visible data only to refuelings that are assigned to a specific car ID.

**Process looks like this:** (we assume that there are data in the database)

After I click on a specific car, I'm getting redirected to cars profile activity where I can see more info about that car.
Then, after choosing an option "Record a fuelling" I'm getting redirected to recyclerview of recorded refuellings of a car that I chosed previously.

**Problem:**

I'm getting every row from table "fuels" after entering the list from cars profile, but I want to see only refuelings that are assigned to this one car.

Here are my 3 activities that matter in this problem:

First one is a list of registered cars
[first activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPnJi.jpg)

Second one is a cars profile
[second activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX0Oz.jpg)

Third one is a list of refuelings
[third activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hZFc.jpg)

(The number on the end of every item on the refuelings list is a ID of a car that I came from and added data to)

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CarsList.db";
    private static final int  DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_CARS = "cars";
    private static final String COLUMN_CAR_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_BRAND = "car_brand";
    private static final String COLUMN_MODEL = "car_model";
    private static final String COLUMN_YEAR_MADE = "car_year_made";

    private static final String TABLE_FUELS = "fuels";
    private static final String COLUMN_FUEL_ID = "fuel_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_STATION_NAME = "station_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_FUEL_TYPE = "fuel_type";
    private static final String COLUMN_FUEL_AMOUNT = "fuel_amount";
    private static final String COLUMN_FUEL_COST = "fuel_cost";
    private static final String COLUMN_MILEAGE = "mileage";
    private static final String COLUMN_FUEL_DATE = "fuel_date";
    private static final String COLUMN_FUELED_CAR_ID = "fueled_car_id";

    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query1 =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CARS +
                        " (" + COLUMN_CAR_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        COLUMN_BRAND + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_MODEL + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_YEAR_MADE + " INTEGER);";
        String query2 =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FUELS +
                        " (" + COLUMN_FUEL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        COLUMN_STATION_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_FUEL_TYPE + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_FUEL_AMOUNT + " INTEGER, " +
                        COLUMN_FUEL_COST + " INTEGER, " +
                        COLUMN_MILEAGE + " INTEGER, " +
                        COLUMN_FUEL_DATE + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_FUELED_CAR_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES "+ COLUMN_CAR_ID + ");";
        db.execSQL(query1);
        db.execSQL(query2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +  TABLE_CARS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +  TABLE_FUELS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addCar(String brand,
                String model,
                int yearMade
    ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_BRAND, brand);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MODEL, model);
        cv.put(COLUMN_YEAR_MADE, yearMade);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_CARS, null, cv);
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed adding new car.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added a new car!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void addFuel(String stationName,
                 String fuelType,
                 int fuelAmount,
                 int fuelCost,
                 int mileage,
                 String fuelDate,
                 String fueledCarId
    ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_STATION_NAME, stationName);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FUEL_TYPE, fuelType);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FUEL_AMOUNT, fuelAmount);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FUEL_COST, fuelCost);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MILEAGE, mileage);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FUEL_DATE, fuelDate);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FUELED_CAR_ID, fueledCarId);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_FUELS, null, cv);
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed adding new refueling.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added a new refueling!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor readAllCars() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor readAllFuels() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FUELS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

**RecyclerFuelAdapter.java**

```
    public class RecyclerFuelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerFuelAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> fuelIds, stationNames, fuelTypes, fuelAmounts, fuelCosts, mileages, fuelDates, fueledCarIds;
    private Context context;
    public RecyclerViewClickListener listener;

    public RecyclerFuelAdapter(Context context,
                               ArrayList<String> fuelIds,
                               ArrayList<String> stationNames,
                               ArrayList<String> fuelTypes,
                               ArrayList<String> fuelAmounts,
                               ArrayList<String> fuelCosts,
                               ArrayList<String> mileages,
                               ArrayList<String> fuelDates,
                               ArrayList<String> fueledCarIds,
                               RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        this.fuelIds = fuelIds;
        this.stationNames = stationNames;
        this.fuelTypes = fuelTypes;
        this.fuelAmounts = fuelAmounts;
        this.fuelCosts = fuelCosts;
        this.mileages = mileages;
        this.fuelDates = fuelDates;
        this.fueledCarIds = fueledCarIds;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerFuelAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View fuelView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fuel, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(fuelView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerFuelAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String $fuelAmount = fuelAmounts.get(position) + "L";
        String $fuelCost = fuelCosts.get(position) + "$";

        holder.fuelIdTv.setText(String.valueOf(fuelIds.get(position)));
        holder.fuelAmountTv.setText($fuelAmount);
        holder.fuelCostTv.setText($fuelCost);
        holder.fuelDateTv.setText(String.valueOf(fuelDates.get(position)));
        holder.fueledCarTv.setText(String.valueOf(fueledCarIds.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fuelIds.size();
    }

    public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
        void onClick(View v, int position);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView fuelIdTv, fuelAmountTv, fuelCostTv, fuelDateTv, fueledCarTv;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            fuelIdTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fuelIdTv);
            fuelAmountTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fuelAmountTv);
            fuelCostTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fuelCostTv);
            fuelDateTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fuelDateTv);
            fueledCarTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fueledCarTv);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

**FuelActivity.java**

```
    public class FuelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String COLUMN_CAR_ID = "_id";
    private DatabaseHelper myDB;
    private RecyclerFuelAdapter.RecyclerViewClickListener listener;
    private ArrayList<String> fuelIds, stationNames, fuelTypes, fuelAmounts, fuelCosts, mileages, fuelDates, fueledCarIds;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerFuelAdapter RecyclerFuelAdapter;
    private Button goToAddFuelBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fuel);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.fuelRecycler);
        goToAddFuelBtn = findViewById(R.id.goToAddFuelBtn);

        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        String value = intent1.getStringExtra(ProfileActivity.COLUMN_CAR_ID);

        goToAddFuelBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddFuelActivity.class);
            intent4.putExtra(COLUMN_CAR_ID, value);
            startActivity(intent4);
        });

        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(FuelActivity.this);
        fuelIds = new ArrayList<>();
        stationNames = new ArrayList<>();
        fuelTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        fuelAmounts = new ArrayList<>();
        fuelCosts = new ArrayList<>();
        mileages = new ArrayList<>();
        fuelDates = new ArrayList<>();
        fueledCarIds = new ArrayList<>();

        storeFuelsInArrays();
        createAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(FuelActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();

    }
    private void createAdapter() {
        setOnClickListener();
        RecyclerFuelAdapter = new RecyclerFuelAdapter(FuelActivity.this, fuelIds, stationNames, fuelTypes, fuelAmounts, fuelCosts, mileages, fuelDates, fueledCarIds,  listener);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(RecyclerFuelAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(FuelActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    private void setOnClickListener() {
        listener = (v, position) -> {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked on " + fuelIds.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        };
    }




    private void storeFuelsInArrays() {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllFuels();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data to be displayed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                fuelIds.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_id")));
                stationNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("station_name")));
                fuelTypes.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_type")));
                fuelAmounts.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_amount")));
                fuelCosts.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_cost")));
                mileages.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mileage")));
                fuelDates.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_date")));
                fueledCarIds.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fueled_car_id")));
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**ProfileActivity.java**

```
    public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String COLUMN_CAR_ID = "_id";
    private TextView myCarID, myCarBrand, myCarModel, myCarYear;
    private Button goToFuelList, goToServiceList;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_activity);

        myCarID = findViewById(R.id.myCarID);
        myCarBrand = findViewById(R.id.myCarBrand);
        myCarModel = findViewById(R.id.myCarModel);
        myCarYear = findViewById(R.id.myCarYear);
        goToFuelList = findViewById(R.id.goToFuelList);
        goToServiceList = findViewById(R.id.goToServiceList);

        myCarID.setText(getCarsData(0));
        myCarBrand.setText(getCarsData(1));
        myCarModel.setText(getCarsData(2));
        myCarYear.setText(getCarsData(3));

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.COLUMN_CAR_ID);

        goToFuelList.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FuelActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra(COLUMN_CAR_ID, value);
            startActivity(intent1);
        });
    }

        @SuppressLint("Recycle")
        private String getCarsData(int option) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("CarsList.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cursor;
            if(db != null) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String value = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.COLUMN_CAR_ID);
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,car_brand,car_model,car_year_made FROM cars WHERE _id = " + value, null);
                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    switch (option) {
                        case 0: buffer.append(cursor.getString(0));
                        break;
                        case 1: buffer.append(cursor.getString(1));
                        break;
                        case 2: buffer.append(cursor.getString(2));
                        break;
                        case 3: buffer.append(cursor.getString(3));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return buffer.toString();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days of trying I've figured it out myself, so if anyone ever will have the same problem which is displaying recyclerview data that depend on value from another recyclerview here is the way that works for me even that it may not be the perfect one.

I simply passed value that stores "_id" column from SQLite table inside intent and checked for it while adding data to ArrayLists.

**FuelActivity.java**

```
private void storeFuelsInArrays() {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllFuels();
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    String checkedValue = intent1.getStringExtra(ProfileActivity.COLUMN_CAR_ID);
    
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No data to be displayed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fueled_car_id"));
            if (value.equals(checkedValue)) {
                fuelIds.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_id")));
                stationNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("station_name")));
                fuelTypes.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_type")));
                fuelAmounts.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_amount")));
                fuelCosts.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_cost")));
                mileages.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mileage")));
                fuelDates.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fuel_date")));
                fueledCarIds.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fueled_car_id")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows better ways to do it, I'd be happy if you could put them in here.